# C++ Array, How should i fix my array, it needs to remove all multiples of a variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I Have to write a function, named filter, that removes all multiples of a variable named num from the given list by calling a function i have written earlier named remove. Here are my two functions. Remove works properly however filter does not. Any input would be nice and i would greatly appreciate it. The filter function is supposed to remove all multiples of num from the program using remove. It currently does nothing and i do not think it entering the loop properly.

```
void remove(int vals[], int sz, int index)
{
    for(int i = index ; i <(sz-1); ++i)
    {
        // shifts down the array once the index element has been removed
        vals[i] = vals[i +1];
    }
    // adds -1 at the end of array once the element has been removed from a certain position. 
    vals[sz - 1] = -1;
}

void filter(int vals[], int sz, int startIndex, int num)
{
    for(int i =2; i< num; i++)
    {
        if( num % i == 0)
        {
            remove( vals, sz, num );
        }
        else if( num % i != 0 );
        {
            cout << num << "is a prime number" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You said that your `filter` function does not work properly. Please tell us how it isn't working. What behavior are you seeing that you shouldn't be seeing?

Comment: Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: There are several things that look strange here, but first of all the suspicious extra semicolon after `else if`.

Comment: Not just a suspicious semicolon but the whole expression is redundant

Comment: Also, `startIndex` is completely unused throughout the function.

Answer (score 1):

A list of problems:

1. You are looping up to num, you should be looping up to sz, as you want to be checking each entry in the array.
2. You aren't checking `num` against the values in `vals`. You need to be checking against `vals[i]`
3. If you remove an item from `vals`, it will be one item shorter, you need to update `sz` with the new count. You also need to work out how you are going to tell the caller that the array is now shorter (unless -1 in the array is OK as a flag).
4. If you remove an item from `vals`, it will be one item shorter, you need to take that into account with your `i` variable, otherwise you will skip an entry after a delete.
5. As @Jon says - you have a semicolon after your else if line.
6. Just because a number is not divisible by a certain other number does not make it prime.